# Specify a service fabric node for API calls

Tags: signalr, azure-service-fabric

In service fabric, is it possible to specify that a set requests are to be processed within the same node.

I am using SignalR in OWIN API with Stateless service fabric and I need the Consecutive SignalR API calls to be executed in a single node because the SignalR uses some kind of Session internally.

If i use a single instance for the Service, it works fine.

Is there a way to define some kind of context during the API calls that those calls will be executed in the same node.

In stateful service with single partition it works fine because all the request is being processed by the primary node. I haven't checked with multiple partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There few solutions:

1. You can partition your service and the use ServicePartitionResolver to choose specific Node (please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication/)
2. You can create your own service that will be instantiated on each node and will return the Node per request. Of course, under the hood the session management should be done within this service.